# How do I correctly nest table properties with SASS?

Tags: sass

This piece of SASS code works:

```
.tableauQuestions
{
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: black;
}

.tableauQuestions td
{
    background-color: $coulCellTabQuestions;
    width: 33%;
    color: $coulTxtTabQuestion;
}
```

But this one yields no formatting for the `table` property.

```
.tableauQuestions
{
   table // also tried: body
   {
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: black;
    }

    td
    {
        background-color: $coulCellTabQuestions;
        width: 33%;
        color: $coulTxtTabQuestion;
    }
}
```

What is it I am doing wrong and *what should the right nested code be*?

EDITING: the HTML is as plain as can be:

```
<table class="tableauQuestions">
    <tr>
        <td>Bon         
        <td>Excellent
        <td>Moyen
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can't say without the HTML code.

Comment: Very good: I have just edited my post.

Comment: `tableauQuestions` is table.

Comment: Indeed. Be more specific…

Comment: @Quentin Veron is right. Remove `table` in `.tableauQuestions` 'cause doesn't exist. `tableauQuestions`is your table!

Comment: @ReSedano — Perhaps… But you do not tell what the right code should be. I have just  re-edited my question.

Comment: I have just sorted it out: the properties pertaining to the 'table' tag (here: tableauQuestions) should not appear between brackets, but just as regular, un-nested properties, then followed by other tags nested the usual way. AMAZINGLY the Firefox css -interpreter complained in the first place about the current efficient solution. Hum… If you refer to https://sass-lang.com/guide you will observe that all nested tags are followed by properties appearing in brackets.

Comment: @QuentinVeron — Si vous êtes intéressé à du travail, mettez-vous en rapport avec moi : coustibri@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The right nested should be the following:

```scss
.tableauQuestions {
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: black;

  td {
    background-color: $coulCellTabQuestions;
    width: 33%;
    color: $coulTxtTabQuestion;
  }
}
```

[About Nesting](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules)